# How can I rearrange the rows of a DataGridView in the code?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView of WinForms, and I want to be able to rearrange the rows using a ListBox located elsewhere. So when I remove an entry from the ListBox, the following line is run:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(e.Index);
```

And when an element is added to the ListBox, the following code is executed:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(e.Index, row);
```

Except that an exception is thrown since the row is in the DataGridView. When I tried to wrap this line with a try block with an empty catch, the row was clearly not there. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: what error do you get?  , i can guess that the error has something to do with the possibility that you try to insert on e.Index , wich is out of range ie it is a higher number than the rows.Count value

Comment: Why don't you create a `BindingSource`,bind it to a `List` or a `DataSet` or whatever your datasource is, then bind both the `ListBox` and `DataGridView` to it.

Comment: Can you show what exception is thrown?

Comment: @Eplzong The exception which is thrown: `InvalidOperationException`

Comment: @Lourayad I'm currently planning on storing the data in the `DataGridView`; the rows represent products, the columns represent stores, and the cell contains the price of the product in the store.